# Robot Framework - return a value from custom keyword

Tags: python, return-value, robotframework

I have this problem where i need to return value that is being generated by a Custom Keyword I have created.

I have two keywords `Get Data` and `Verify Signal R` I am generating a value in the  `Verify Signal R` keyword that calls the Get data function, I need to verify that I got some kind of message back here is the code

```
def get_data(notificaition):
    print("Notification Recived: ", notificaition)
    return notificaition

def verify_signal_r():

    print(connection)
    presenceservice1.client.on('StaffPresenceNotified', get_data)
    connection.wait(15)
    return presenceservice1
```

And then my Keywords

```
*** Variables ***

${Notification}

*** Keywords ***

Verify Notification Was Displayed
    get connection
    Doctor Has Entered The Room
    verify signal r
    get data  ${Notification}
```

and then my log

[image]

As you can see I am priting the message within the Verify Singal R keyword but the get data is empty how can i return a value from python method/Keyword?

***EDIT***  I am printing the message inside the `Verify Signal R` but when I try to just call the `get data` which prints out the message I get an empty field as you can see in my log Thats because the `get data` uses the generated value from `Verify Signal R` and if I just call the get data method its empty as expected , I am trying to verify that get data is not empty and i got a message back from the server.

Hope that makes it clearer

Comment: Hi, could you rephrase your question? I am not sure what's your problem here.

Comment: @JaPyR I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by creating another method and using a `global` to pass the data

```
def get_data(self, notification):
    global var2
    var2 = notification
    print("Message Received From Client!")


def print_data(self):

    print(var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Log` Keyword to print the value in the Log.
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log

Answer (score 0):

Probably I struggle to understand your problem because I don't see any strange behavior. I'll start from the end.

1. Keyword `get data` prints nothing because `${Notification}` variable is empty from the beginning and never was modified.
2. I assume that in case of keyword `verify signal r` you have `Notification received: {....}` because `presenceservice1.client.on('StaffPresenceNotified', get_data)` invokdes `get_data` with some argument

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want this.
Just add **${data}=** in front of your keyword ( with/without **'='** both fine)

```
*** Keywords ***

Verify Notification Was Displayed
    get connection
    Doctor Has Entered The Room
    verify signal r
    ${data}=  get data  ${Notification}
    Log  ${data}
```